# Constructing bicentric pentagon

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polygons, math-software

I'm trying to construct a bicentric pentagon in geogebra. I read on Wikipedia that a Pentagon is bicentric if and only if it satisfies this formula $$r(R-x)=(R+x)\left(\sqrt{(R-r)^2-x^2}+\sqrt{2R(R-r-x)}\right)$$
where $R,r$ and $x$ are respectively the radius of the circumcircle, the radius of the incircle and the distance between the centers.
So one way to do this is by finding three (exact) values $R,r$ and $x$ and  plugging them in geogebra. Is there any known values that work?

Comment: FYI, eliminating the square roots gives a polynomial equation that factors as $$ y\left(y^3
 - 8 y^2 r R
 + 16 y r^2 R^2
 + 8 y r^3 R
 - 16 r^4 R^2\right)=0, \quad y:=x^2-R(R-2r)$$
The first factor corresponds to [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry) for triangles, so is extraneous. The second factor is cubic in $y$, hence is explicitly solvable in terms of $r$ and $R$; from $y$, one can obtain $x$.

Comment: Well $y$ is not $0$ @Blue

Comment: *"Well $y$ is not $0$"* ... That's why I said that the first factor is extraneous. :)

Comment: @Blue Your remark is very interesting. But I am faced with it with the following problem : I have attempted to browse many cases, with a program covering a large "spectrum" of values of $R$ and $r$. The third degree equation has always a single real root for $y$ (two complex roots ; I haven't computed the discriminant, but surely it is negative). But, the values of $x$ one gets from the $y$ values do not lead to a good between-centers distance for having a bicentric polygon. Why that ? Is it that the relationship is a necessary only (non sufficient) condition for having a bicentric pentagon ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: Hmmm ... Well, I don't vouch for the [Wikipedia relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicentric_polygon#Polygons_with_n_%3E_4), which appears to be taken from [MathWorld's "Poncelet's Porism" entry](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PonceletsPorism.html). (Of course, I don't even vouch for my own work! :) I've just tried a quick GeoGebra sketch using the cubic solution to calculate $y$ (and $x$), but it seems I'm not getting any bicentric pentagons, either. Curious.

Comment: @Blue An interesting document [here](https://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jgg/jgg17/j17h2mcan.pdf) : see page 8 where the author finds a factorisation similar to yours.

Comment: From the same author, a [2015 article](https://go.gale.com/ps/i.do?id=GALE%7CA673737253&sid=googleScholar&v=2.1&it=r&linkaccess=abs&issn=19332823&p=AONE&sw=w&userGroupName=anon%7E2a7bf99e&aty=open-web-entry) behind a paywall...

Answer (score 2):

We pursue an alternate construction in which the parameters are angles of the pentagon.

Let $ABCDE$ be a mirror-symmetric pentagon inscribed in the unit circle, with vertices

$A=(0,1), B=(\sin\theta,\cos\theta), C=(\sin\theta,-\cos\theta), D=(-\sin\theta,-\cos\theta), E=(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$

Then the $y$ axis is an angle bisector and the other angle bisectors form two pairs concurrent with this axis at the points indicated:

$B,E\to(0,\cos\theta-\tan(45°-\theta/4)\sin\theta)$

$C,D\to(0,\sin\theta-\cos\theta)$

To make the pentagon bicentric these concurrency points are to be matched. This leads to

$2\cos\theta-([1+\tan(45°-\theta/4)]\sin\theta)=0$

$[1+\tan(45°-\theta/4)]\tan\theta=2$

We convert this to a polynomial equation by defining $x=\tan(\theta/4)$. From trigonometric identities we have

$\tan(45°-\theta/4)=(1-x)/(1+x)$

$\tan\theta=4(x-x^3)/(1-6x^2+x^4)$

leading to a quintic equation:

$x^5+x^4-2x^3-6x^2-3x+1=0.$

This quintic turns out to be reducible, with $x+1$ as a factor. Dividing this out leaves

$x^4-2x^2-4x+1=0,$

in which the resolvent cubic has no rational roots and therefore this pentagon will not be constructible via unmarked straightedge and compasses (and algebraically, the roots are unwieldy). To get a convex polygon we must find a root corresponding to $0°<\theta<90°$, from which $0<x<\tan(22.5°)=\sqrt2-1$. Numerical calculation reveals that to five decimal places the appropriate root is $x\approx0.22527$ from which **$\theta\approx50°47'$**.

We may compare this with what we would have gotten with nicer values of $\theta$. On the left below, we have what would be obtained with $\theta=45°$ by matching the vertices of the pentagon to those of a regular octagon; the proposed incircle does not reach the bottom side of the pentagon because we made $\theta$, the arc from $A$ to $B$, too small. If we try $\theta=60°$ by matching the vertices of the pentagon to those of a regular hexagon, we see the opposite problem. The calculated root falls in the expected range between these two misses.

[image]

The implication is that if (except for the regular case) we want "nice" values for any angles, we have to get not-so-nice ones for the other geometric properties.

Comment: Do you mean that non-regular bicentric pentagons are not constructible ?

Comment: That would not surprise me. Given a general set of side lengths, pentagons inscribed in a circle turn out not to be constructibel — even with neusis.

Comment: Is this the case with any non-regular polygon? (n>4)

Comment: It only gets worse as $n$ increases.